# Adding "username not available" to SQLite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have created a register and login page through the `SQLite database`. I am trying to create a function where new users who would like to register will not be able to register if their username is similar to that of another created account.

I would also need there to be a prompt stating, `"Username not available"` when users try to.  I did attempt to code it in my database helper but it causes my `android-studio` to crash unexpectedly, hence I have removed them. **I have tried** searching for tutorials online but to no avail.

**Activity Database Helper:**

```java
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "register.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "registeruser";

    //Column 1 is for ID
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";

    //Column 2 is for username
    public static final String COL_2 = "username";

    //Column 3 is for password
    public static final String COL_3 = "password";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null , 1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE registeruser (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,username TEXT, password TEXT)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int ii) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

    }

    //function to add new users when registering
    public long adduser (String user, String password)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("username", user);
        contentValues.put("password", password);
        long res = db.insert("registeruser",null,contentValues);
        db.close();
        return res;

    }

    //function to check if user exists
    public boolean checkUser(String username, String password)
    {
        String[] columns = { COL_1};
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String selection = COL_2 + "=?" + " and " + COL_3 + "=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { username, password };
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,columns,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        if(count>0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int updatePassword(String username, String newPassword){

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("password",newPassword);
        String whereClause = "username = ?";
        String[] whereArgs = { username };
        int result = db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues,whereClause,whereArgs);

        db.close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Activity Registeractivity:**

```java
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper db;
    EditText mTextUsername;
    EditText mTextPassword;
    EditText mTextCnfPassword;
    ImageButton mButtonRegister;
    TextView mTextViewLogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);


        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        mTextUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_username);
        mTextPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_password);
        mTextCnfPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_cnf_password);
        mButtonRegister = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton_register);
        mTextViewLogin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_login);
        mTextViewLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent LoginIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginPageActivity.class);
                startActivity(LoginIntent);
            }
        });

        mButtonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String user = mTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
                String pwd = mTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                String cnf_pwd = mTextCnfPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if(pwd.length() > 0 && user.length() > 0 && pwd.equals(cnf_pwd)) {
                    Long val = db.adduser(user,pwd);
                    if(val > 0){
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Successfully Registered.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent movetoLogin = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginPageActivity.class);
                        startActivity(movetoLogin);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Registration Error.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Check Your Fields Again.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the error log.

Comment: there is no errorr log, when i build it, my android studio stops responding till i remove those codes

Comment: @HarishRaaj I suggest using `Room` database library for SQLite operations. It will help a lot later while making any operations related to database.

Comment: Try Using Room Database instead of this

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

**Activity Database Helper:**

```
public boolean CheckUserName(String UserName){

    SQLiteDatabase databaseToRead = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = databaseToRead.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME WHERE YOUR_COLUM_NAME_OF_USERNAME=?",new String[]{UserName});
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Activity Registeractivity :**

Add this inside your onClickListener.

```
String input_from_edittext = your_edittext_variable.getText().toString().trim();
DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
boolean check_username = helper.CheckUserName(input_from_edittext );
            if (check_username == true) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This Username is not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {/*Register User*/ }
```